# Is there a difference between ElementwiseLayer@Ramp and Ramp in NetGraph?

Tags: neural-networks

[image]

This is about neural net! I put what I want to ask in the picture! This is the code!

```
NetGraph[{Ramp, Tanh, LogisticSigmoid}, {1 -> 3}]

NetGraph[{ElementwiseLayer@Ramp, ElementwiseLayer@Tanh, 
          ElementwiseLayer@LogisticSigmoid}, {1 -> 3}]
```

Comment: I have heard of net neutrality but have never heard of a `neutral net`. Since I don't have much experience with what you are doing, I hope that someone will help you in due course of time.

Comment: That is Artificial neural network, sorry, my mistake. About deep learning.

Comment: @Syed  its neural net

Answer (score 4):

```
nn = NetGraph[{Ramp, Tanh, LogisticSigmoid}, {1 -> 3}] // FullForm

mm = NetGraph[{ElementwiseLayer@Ramp, ElementwiseLayer@Tanh, 
    ElementwiseLayer@LogisticSigmoid}, {1 -> 3}] // FullForm

mm==nn
```

> (* True *)

The expressions are the same.

Comment: Ok  really really clear, good point. Thanks